# YouTube iFrame unclickable because of margins (Bootstrap)

Tags: javascript, html, css, iframe, youtube

I have a problem with my YouTube iFrame: it becomes not clickable when I set margin (negative ones). And that is not what I want! I would like the visitor to be able to play the video on my website.

To add a bit more context, it is a Bootstrap website, and the video is in a timeline. I set negative margins, so that I do not lose space on the page. If I do not set margins, I get a left item - everything on the right is blank -, then after scrolling to the end of the first item, I get the second one on the right - but everything is blank on the left, and so on... 
I tried to use relative and absolute positions, but it does not work in bootstrap timelines (every item crash together when I change it).

Do you have any idea or clue about this issue?

Here is what my HTML looks like:

```
<li style="margin-top: -140px">
      <div class="timeline-badge"><i class="fa fa-gamepad" id="round"></i></div>
      <div class="timeline-panel">
        <div class="timeline-heading">
          <h4 class="timeline-title">Solitaire Android app</h4>
          <p><small class="text-muted"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-time"></i> November 2016 - Work in Progress</small></p>
        </div>
        <div class="timeline-body">
          <p style="margin-bottom: 10px;">This solitaire card game is an Android application, that tells the player when there is no more move to do.
          This feature exists on iOS but not on Android, as far as I know. 
          So I wanted to do this to avoid the player to lose time in looking for a solution that does not exist.
          You can play by dragging and dropping cards on the screen.
          I plan to publish it on the Play Store! </p>
            <div class="embed-responsive embed-responsive-16by9">
            <iframe class="embed-responsive-item" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/A2nMAct2w88"></iframe>
          </div>
          <p style="margin-top: 10px;"><i>Technologies used: Java, Android</i></p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </li>
```

And here is a link to my WIP-website, if it can help :)

http://horlogehumaine.net16.net/slegras/code.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you talking about the small video in, say, "Solitaire Android App"?

If so, it's being relatively positioned among other relative/absolutely positioned things that are "covering" it.

Give **.embed-responsive** a **z-index:1;**